# Formula for a countdown in days not working: including text in formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

G24 - today() "days"

G24: 2021-10-18

Why doesn't above work? It's a countdown towards a set date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either "&" or [Concatenate()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) to combine your data/text in a cell.

**Formula:**

```
=G24-today() &" days"
=Concatenate(G24-today()," days")
```

**Output:**

[image]